# Datasource not updating cells

Tags: ios, swift

When I'm trying to update my datasource (which is custom in a separate class) from a closure inside the respective ViewController it won't work.

So this is the code I'm calling to update the datasource with

```
extension YelpSearchController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    guard let searchTerm = searchController.searchBar.text else {
        return
    }

    let yelpCoordinate = YLPCoordinate(latitude: 37.785834000000001, longitude: -122.406417)
    let yelpClient = YLPClient.init(apiKey: appSecret)
    yelpClient.search(with: yelpCoordinate, term: searchTerm , limit: 30, offset: 1, sort: YLPSortType.distance) { [weak self] result, error in
        guard let results = result else { return }
        let businesses = results.businesses
        self?.dataSource.update(with: businesses)           
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the function that is just updating my data variable inside the datasource class, as follows:

```
private var data = [YLPBusiness]()
func update(with data: [YLPBusiness]) {
    self.data = data
}
```

The problem is when I call the delegate methods, as required as a datasource, they are initially called but when they are the data variable has still not been updated, so the data is nil.

If I for example try and print the data.count inside of the update func I get a result. But inside of any of the delegate methods (cellForRowAt, numberOfRowsInSection), it's all nil. So all the methods concerning and using the data variable except the update function they are not getting the data since the view is loading but the data comes after when the user inputs in the search field.

So the question is how do I get the data accessible to the delegate methods?

Comment: Are you reloading your tableview *after* receiving the data?

Comment: @DonMag Dude!!! You're the best. Such a stupid mistake, I just added: 
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }

Everything works now! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to update the datasource after I've received the data from inside the closure.

```
yelpClient.search(with: yelpCoordinate, term: searchTerm , limit: 30, offset:    1, sort: YLPSortType.distance) { [weak self] result, error in
        guard let results = result else { return }
        let businesses = results.businesses
            self?.dataSource.update(with: businesses)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {. // added this 
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Big thanks to DonMag for the correct answer.